# Can't mount moto e(android phone) on usb 2.0 as media device

Tags: mount, android, automount

can't mount moto e(android phone) on usb 2.0 as media device but works with usb 3.0. Even with usb 3.0, only files can be copied but not the directories.

Comment: I don't recall encountering any issues when I recently setup a Moto E for a relative. Regarding the USB connectivity, please try another computer, if 2.0 ports work with the other computer, than it's likely to be a bug with your computer that should be reported to launchpad.

Comment: pendrives are working good with 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if your device/USB vendor is supported by libmtpfs.

Please post the output of `lsusb -v` or google something like "libmtp supported device moto e" plus vendor ID. You will find entries like http://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/bugs/1053/ which indicate support is not available for that combination.